# Likelihood ratio test in R

Tags: r, self-study, likelihood-ratio

I am in desperate need for help. I am trying to calculate the likehood ratio test in R, but I don't have allot of experience using R.

For example, to calculate the following

Suppose $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n$ is a random sample from a normal population with mean $\mu$ and variance $16$. Find the test with the best critical region, that is, find the most powerful test, with a sample size of $n = 16$ and a significance level $\alpha = 0.05$ to test the simple null hypothesis $H_0: \mu = 10$ against the simple alternative hypothesis $H_A: \mu = 15$.

This is the code I have up until now

```
#X values
#Added the mean=10 thanks to the comments here
X=rnorm(16,10,sd=4)

mlog1=function(media,x,sdev){
sum(-dnorm(x,mean=media, sd=sdev, log=T))
}

#L(10)
#also added sdev
out1=nlm(mlog1,10,x=X,sdev=4)
#L(15)
#also added sdev
out2=nlm(mlog1,15,x=X,sdev=4)

k1=out1$estimate
    k2=out2$estimate

#L(10)/L(15)    
print( k1/k2)
```

This is the very basic axample and the solution, done by hand, can be found [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/307).

I know you also have the LRT function, but I don't know how to apply this function.

Please help, the code looks correct but it always returns 1 or 0.9999999 for any value in the parameters.

Comment: There are some odd things about this question.  You know the variance (normally the last thing we even estimate), sample size - coincidentally and confusingly exactly the same as the sample size - , two very precise hypotheses but not the actual data.  If your question is about exploring this sort of data in R I would start with simulating data in the right range but put aside the red herring of the sample size being the same as the variance eg half way between mean of 10 an 15 eg  rnorm(100,12.5,16).  And then testing your code against that.  Your current sample code has a mean of zero.

Comment: Hi Peter, thankyou for your comment. This is actually an assigment I have to do for colledge and my knowledge is a bit limited. What I am trying to do here is to demonstrate how to obtain the likelihood ratio using R, and for that demonstration I got a solved example and now I am trying to obtain the same result using R. I have already changed the mean to 10 (that was a mistake of mine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @Henry's answer and to @PeterEllis' comment, here are a few comments about the R code itself:

- The third argument of `mlog1` is `sdev`. You therefore need `sdev` in `out1` and `out2` (not `sd`);
- The likelihood ratio test is the logarithm of the ratio between two likelihoods (up to a multiplicative factor). Equivalently, it is a difference between two log-likelihoods (up to a multiplicative factor). It is not the ratio between two log-likelihoods.
- `k1=out1$estimate` returns an estimate of $\mu$. `k2=out2$estimate` returns another estimate of $\mu$ (based on another starting value). Both aim to estimate the same thing; that's why you always get something very close to $1$.
  Neither of them returns minus a log-likelihood.
- You forgot the multiplicative factor ($-2$).

Comment: Hi Ocram, how can I obtain this diference? can you give an example?

Comment: Sorry @jON45, it is not clear to me what your R code is intented to do...

Comment: It's just the most simple example on how to calculate the likehood ratio in R. I thougth I was doing the code correctly, but apperantly I am not. Can you suggest anything? Just one thing, what I am trying to accomplish here is the Neyman-Pearson Lemma

Comment: Your lecture notes explain that it suffices to compute the sample mean and to compare it with a critical value.

Comment: I see, I was being dumb. I don't need to calculate all this. The likelihood ratio was just the mean to get to this conclusion. But what if I need to calculate the Likelihood ratio? How can I do it?

Comment: Your mlog1 function computes minus the log-likelihood of a sample given a mean and a std deviation. You can compute the difference between two log-likelihoods by giving different values for the mean.

Answer (score 1):

`X=rnorm(16,sd=4)` generates normal random variables with standard deviation $4$ and mean $0$.

Given the choice between these being thought to be generated from a similar distribution with mean $10$ and a distribution with mean $15$, the former will appear to be overwhelmingly more likely.

Comment: Hi Henry, thank you so much for your reply. I have changed th code, but I keep getting the same problem, he always gives me 1.

Comment: Hi Henry, thank you so much for your reply. I have changed th code, but I keep getting the same problem, he always gives me 1. Please have a look at the example here https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/307. I think my problem is not knowing the exact value I shoudl, I am expecting something close to 0.9996 but I always get 1 or 0.9999996.